# panic button hide tabs accidently

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I installed panic button extension of google chrome browser. Sometimes when I close another application using `alt+F4` the extension will hide all tabs currently there. But it does not always happen. what's wrong with it?

EDIT:`F4` does lead to that. I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of PanicButton:
*You can also use PanicButton's keyboard shortcut. Just press F4 to hide and restore all your tabs. (currently only works when you're on a http:// or https:// page)*

I believe it just sometimes intercepts the alt-f4 if chrome is the second-last open window when closing another application, play with it and see if you can reproduce? `F4` is for sure the keyboard shortcut for PanicButton, but as it says, only works if the current active TAB is currently visiting a http/https URL.